# How to refactor this unfound collector sql for mysql so it is faster

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, query-optimization

I have a block of sql I use to find all items from one table that don't have a matching value in another table. It currently it works but it is slow.

```
SELECT it.id,it.standard_part_number FROM items it
      WHERE NOT EXISTS ( 
        SELECT 1 FROM part_numbers pn
          WHERE pn.account_id = 1 
            AND pn.value = it.standard_part_number 
            AND pn.standard = 1 
      )
```

There is already an index for part_numbers table on account_id, value, and standard.

Is it possible to make this faster?

**Update:**

I accepted the suggestion that this was a duplicate but I am also adding what I did to make it faster here in case it helps anyone in the future:

```
SELECT it.id,it.standard_part_number FROM items it
      WHERE it.id NOT IN ( 
        SELECT pn.item_id FROM part_numbers pn
          WHERE pn.account_id = 1 
            AND pn.value = it.standard_part_number 
            AND pn.standard = 1 
      )
```

The other question and the article it is linked to were very helpful.
This is the article that was helpful http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/

In case it is useful to anyone, I ended up having to recreate the index to be 4 columns (for other reasons outside of this question) and the time to execute the original query when the part numbers table had 19378 rows in it, the items table had 78266 rows in it and there were 74466 rows in items table that were unfound in part numbers table based on the conditions specified was approximately 245 seconds. When I changed the query to use it.id NOT IN instead of NOT EXISTS and using the same conditions, it now executes in less than 1 second.

Comment: Have you tried a simple left join with a null check to see if it's faster?

Comment: can you please post sample data so we can test that modifying query according to data

Comment: @christutty, can you give me an example of a null check on a left join? Do you mean to check to see if the join itself is not null?

Comment: Is that one composite inex, or 3 separate indexes?  (It makes a big difference.)  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: Which table is bigger?  What percentage of rows have acct=1 and std=1?  It may be better to use a `JOIN` so that it can start with `pn` instead if `it`.

Comment: The other issue linked as possible duplicate and the further article linked in that issue solved my problem. Using where it.id NOT IN instead of NOT EXISTS dramatically sped things up, especially after I ended up needing to add a 4th column to the index for other reasons.